# On coefficients of $(t-x_1)(t-x_2)..(t-x_i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

I was reading Emil Artin's *Galois Theory* (2nd edition). On pp.39-40, Artin defines a number of things as follows.

Let $k$ be a field and $E=k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be the field of all rational functions of $n$ indeterminates $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Define a polynomial
$$
f(t)=(t-x_1)\cdots(t-x_n)=t^n+a_1t^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n,\tag{3}
$$
where $a_1=-\sum_ix_i,\,a_2=\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j$,... are elementary symmetric functions in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Then he puts $F_n(t)=f(t)$ and also for $i=n-1,\,n-2,\ldots,1$,
$$
F_i(t)=\frac{f(t)}{(t-x_{i+1})(t-x_{i+2})\cdots(t-x_n)}=\frac{F_{i+1}(t)}{t-x_{i+1}}.\tag{5}
$$
(If I am not mistaken, this simply means that $F_i(t)=(t-x_1)(t-x_2)..(t-x_i)$ for each $i$, but what matters below is the division on the RHS of $(5)$.) He then writes that (emphasis mine):

> Performing the division [in $(5)$] we see that $F_i(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$ of degree $i$ whose highest coefficient is $1$ and **whose coefficients are polynomials in the variables $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_i$ and $x_{i+1},x_{i+2},\ldots,x_n$**. Only integer enter as coefficients in these expressions.

Can someone explain the bold part? I have thought about using Euclidean algorithm, but the $a_i$s are polynomials in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ rather than constants. I am not sure how the division is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just perform polynomial division as if the symbols were numbers. For example, you can check that
$$
(t^3+a_1t^2+a_2t+a_3)\div(t-x_3)=t^2+(a_1+x_3)t+[(a_1+x_3)x_3+a_2]
$$
and
$$
\left(t^2+(a_1+x_3)t+[(a_1+x_3)x_3+a_2]\right)\div(t-x_2)=t+(a_1+x_2+x_3).
$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!